# Stripe subscribers not being charged

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, stripe-payments

I have a client which has about 400 customers created in Stripe. All of them with some type of subscription with trial end today (1st of march).

Only about 40 of them has been tried charged the amount of the subscription.

When can I expect the rest to be charged? Earlier today I confirmed our ownership of our domain. Can that have anything to do with it?

I hope you can help since it is quite important that we get the money as quick as possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There was a delay because of the abnormal short month.
The answer was posted on Twitter: https://twitter.com/thegdb/status/572079855770075137